# C# DataGridView edit cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

All. I've been googling this question for an hour now and still can't understand how it works. I have DataGridView control on my form, which has 3 columns + 1 ButtonColumn, to which I add lines like this:

```
dg.Rows.Add(param1, param2, param3);
```

The text for the button is set like this:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn bc = (DataGridViewButtonColumn)dg.Columns["ButtonColumn"];
bc.Text = "Action";
bc.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Now, I want to change specific button's text, once user clicked on it, to, let's say "Done". I tried it like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell)) {
        DataGridViewButtonCell cell = (DataGridViewButtonCell)articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            articles.CurrentCell = cell;
            articles.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            articles.BeginEdit(false);
            cell.Value = "Done";
            articles.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work. I've tried a few answers to a similar questions here, on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work as well. Forgive me if I overlooked something. Would anyone be so kind to explain me how to do this, and why doesn't this work?

**UPDATE:**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell)) {
         articles.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
         articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "Done";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
if (articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell)) {

articles.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
articles.ReadOnly = false;
articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = false;
articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
articles.CurrentCell = articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
articles.BeginEdit(true);
if (articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].IsInEditMode) { //it's false here
    articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "Done";
}
articles.EndEdit();
}
}
```

I can't even change the Value manually in debugger, it's immediately set back to the old value.
The problem seems to be sepcific to the DataGridViewButtonCell, because cells of other types change fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change from using cell.Value to

```
articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "Done";
```

Changing cells value only changes if you add that cell back to the datagridview.
This way you can get rid of using the cell like this.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (articles.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonColumn)) {
            articles.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
            articles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "Done";
    }
}
```

I edited out the rest as I don't believe it is needed for what you are doing.

Comment: @Stranger1399 What happens ? Doesn't work isn't a good explanation.

Comment: Fair enough. The value stays the same, and when i step through the code in debug mode it doesn't change.

Comment: @Stranger1399 Try the above code. It should work I just tested it on my DataGridView. I use the cell click event not the cell content click event for the data grid view. I'm not sure if the cell content click event works with the above or not.

Comment: Still nothing. The cell itself doesn't have EditMode property. I had to changed it to articles.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically, otherwise it wouldn't compile. Maybe that's where my problem lies?

Windows XP, VisualStudio 2010, .NET 4.0

Comment: @Stranger1399 Sorry I accidently changed that to the cell. The editemode should be for your datagridview. Check to make sure the editmode is getting changed. It should be working though.

Comment: Editmode is getting changed, but the cell value doesn't.

Comment: Can you post in your original post the new method you are using ?

Comment: @Stranger1399 Only other thing I can think of is that you set the cell to readonly in some other method try the new code posted.

Comment: ReadOnly was somehow set to true, however changing it had no effect. And in the DataGridView property window readonly is set to false.

Comment: @Stranger1399 Make sure that the datagridview articles.Readonly = false; is also set.

Comment: All readonlys are set to true and still nothing. Updated original post

Comment: @Stranger1399 You do know they all need to be set to false not true ?

Comment: Of course, just a mistype. Look at the code in the updated pos, all false.

Comment: You do not need the articles.BeginEdit(true); or the if check to see if it is in edit mode. That will cause the problem right there.

Comment: The problem seems to be sepcific to the DataGridViewButtonCell, because cells of other types change fine.

Comment: There must be something different in your version then. I am using the newest .net version and vs 2013 and the above works fine. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line of code:

```
bc.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

When it's set, it's not possible to edit ButtonCell's value.
Any readonly option of the DataGridView is irrelevant here, they specify if the user, not you, can edit cells.

Thanks for your help,  @deathismyfriend